# BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default... Polyfill

Tags: node.js, reactjs, polyfills

So I am creating an Instagram clone using React.js and Firebase, and ran into an issue while working on the file upload portion of the app. The error read:

"BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:

- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
- install 'querystring-es3'
  If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
  resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }"

I am beyond confused on how to move forward...

Comment: I solved it! I went into my node_modules folder -> react-instagram -> es -> index.js -> line 39 -> Added: "resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") };"
Then, in terminal console, typed "npm install querystring".

Boom, working!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'querystring' was depricated and my `npm run build` command is freaking out as this line was used somewhere, which I commented out:

```
//import { stringify } from 'querystring';
```

And use this instead:

```
JSON.stringify()
```

Looking at the above mentioned error I tried installing
npm i querystring-es3
Eventually I didn't need that and uninstalled the same.